# Python Flask Application deployment on IIS

Tags: python, flask, iis, fastcgi

I am using this tutorial as reference [click here](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8)

and trying to host my application on our intranet server.

The application works perfectly with waitress but doesnt run well with IIS fast CGI

Code

```
  import pyodbc
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from config.Database_Details import cursor
import re
import time    
from datetime import datetime,date
import ctypes
from waitress import serve


app = Flask(__name__)
ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()

class PrefixMiddleware(object):
#class for URL sorting 
    def __init__(self, app, prefix=''):
        self.app = app
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if environ['PATH_INFO'].lower().replace('/Checker','').startswith(self.prefix):
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'].lower().replace('/Checker','')[len(self.prefix):]
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.prefix
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
        else:
            start_response('404', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])            
            return ["This url does not belong to the app.".encode()]


app.wsgi_app = PrefixMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, prefix='/check')

@app.route('/home/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    print("hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='xx.xxx.xx.xxx', port=5000)
```

[image]

error message

[image]

Comment: Is using IIS as a reverse proxy an option
https://medium.com/@rbtlonger/iis-reverse-proxy-to-web-apps-nginx-python-php-golang-java-8bdb1bbd2281

Comment: wfastcgi is a dead project now. That blog post you followed is out of date.

Comment: check your iis binding for the flask site and see the iis error log for more detail.

Comment: @LexLi could you suggest some other method?

Comment: @John followed the process still same error.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal no major information available apart from giving me error codes like 400 or 503

Comment: Review the site bindings you set please, as they are the common sources of 400, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background